# Automator Application as 'Login Items' to 'Connect to Servers' - Servers don't display in Finder Side Bar?

Tags: finder, automator, login, afp

Have an Automator Application as a 'Login Items' to 'Connect to Servers' (AFP).

On login it runs, connects the servers, but does not add them to the Finder Side Bar under 'Devices'.

Once logged in, I disconnect the servers manually, and then run the Application manually. The servers connect & are added to the Finder side bar! Same, unmodified Application.

Have tried to add a 'Pause' of a few seconds to the Automator Application at the start, but it still won't work.

This exact same Automator Application used to work in Snow Leopard without fail. Stopped working with the upgrade to Mountain Lion. Have opened & re-saved the Application using Automator on Mountain Lion as well.

Any suggestions?

**Added (30-SEP-12) ...**

Finder directly after login & Automator script has run.

[image: Finder directly after login & Automator script has run.]

Run Automator script manually.

[image: Run Automator script manually.]

Finder after running Automator script manually.

[image: Finder after running Automator script manually.]

Also, just discovered something new. During login, if I quickly open Finder, while the script is starting/running, the mappings are created (!), but if I don't open Finder, let the script run, then the mappings are not created.

**Added (01-OCT-12) ...**

Workaround ... add a 'Get Specified Finder Items', and then an 'Open Finder Items' to open Finder before attempting to connect to the servers.

[image: Workaround]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of it working after running the application manually?

Comment: Sure @Robin, added above.

Comment: After reading your last update, did you try adding Open Finder to your script? Under Utilities > Launch Application. Maybe that would do the trick?

Comment: @Melwan - Yes that works. Have added info to above post. Just not elegant. Could it be a security feature they added in OS X 10.8? or something they broke?

Comment: Is there a reason that you use an automator script over just dragging mounted drives to your login items? Neatness of having it all in one file?

Comment: Hi @Robin, I tried that when I moved from Lion to Mountain Lion and the Automator script stopped adding the connected servers to the Finder side bar. It either did the same thing & didn't add them to the Finder side bar, or totally stuffed up in the Login Items - the connected server would change from one server to a different one (If I had 5 different ones, the last 4 would change to the first one). Basically it didn't work. Automator with the workaround above works every time :)